# Getting the column name that holds the maximum value of a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have generated an extensive view which simulates certain occurrences based on different statistic models. These models are defined in each column header by a number and the maximum value of a row is the best model.

The table generated looks (partially) as follows;

```
+--------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Number | LI | PHSE | 0505 | 0506 | 0507 | 0508 | 0509 | [...] etc.
+--------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 100254 | 2  | M1   |   44 |   46 |   45 |   44 |   44 |
| 100254 | 2  | M2   |   36 |   36 |   35 |   37 |   37 |
| 100254 | 2  | M3   |    5 |    5 |    5 |    5 |    5 |
| 100254 | 2  | R1   |   34 |   36 |   37 |   37 |   37 |
| 100254 | 2  | R2   |   41 |   41 |   40 |   41 |   41 |
| 100329 | 1  | M1   |   37 |   38 |   38 |   38 |   39 |
| 100329 | 1  | M2   |   31 |   29 |   28 |   29 |   29 |
| 100329 | 1  | M3   |    6 |    6 |    6 |    6 |    6 |
| 100329 | 1  | R1   |   29 |   29 |   29 |   30 |   30 |
| 100329 | 1  | R2   |   25 |   26 |   26 |   27 |   26 |
+--------+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+
  [...] etc.
```

Now I want to find the highest value in each **row** and display the corresponding column name as such;

```
| Number | LI | PHSE | MAXCOL |
+--------+----+------+--------+
| 100254 | 2  | M1   |   0506 |
| 100254 | 2  | M2   |   0508 |
| 100254 | 2  | M3   |   0505 |
| 100254 | 2  | R1   |   0507 |
| 100254 | 2  | R2   |   0505 |
+--------+----+------+--------+
  [...] etc.
```

This is derived from 100254 - 2 - M1 largest value 46 occurring in column 0506, etc.

I've been toying around with `PIVOT` functions but no success there. I've also looked for an Index/Match equivalent like in Excel but since I can't refer to column headers as values this obviously won't work (and haven't found such function either).

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

---

UPDATE per Damien's comment:

An excerpt from the code that led to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub2.Number, sub2.LI, sub2.PHSE
, sum(sub2.[0505]) over (partition by sub2.Number, sub2.LI, sub2.PHSE) as '0505'
, sum(sub2.[0506]) over (partition by sub2.Number, sub2.LI, sub2.PHSE) as '0506'
[...] etc. /*64 rows*/

FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT sub.*
    , CASE WHEN sub.MF > sub.[5PAV] - sub.[5PSTDEV] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS '0505'
    , CASE WHEN sub.MF > sub.[5PAV] - sub.[6PSTDEV] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS '0506'
    [...] etc. /*64 rows*/

    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT ra.*
        , sum(ra.qtyr) OVER (partition BY ra.Number, ra.LI, ra.PHSE ORDER BY (ra.Number) rows BETWEEN 5 preceding AND 1 preceding) / 
        sum(ra.qtyu) OVER (partition BY ra.Number, ra.LI, ra.PHSE ORDER BY (ra.Number) rows BETWEEN 5 preceding AND 1 preceding) AS '5PAV'
        , sum(ra.qtyr) OVER (partition BY ra.Number, ra.LI, ra.PHSE ORDER BY (ra.Number) rows BETWEEN 6 preceding AND 1 preceding) / 
        sum(ra.qtyu) OVER (partition BY ra.Number, ra.LI, ra.PHSE ORDER BY (ra.Number) rows BETWEEN 6 preceding AND 1 preceding) AS '6PAV'
        [...] etc. /*8 rows*/

        , stdev(ra.MF) OVER (partition BY ra.Number, ra.LI, ra.PHSE ORDER BY (ra.Number) rows BETWEEN 4 preceding AND CURRENT row) AS '5PSTDEV'
        , stdev(ra.MF) OVER (partition BY ra.Number, ra.LI, ra.PHSE ORDER BY (ra.Number) rows BETWEEN 5 preceding AND CURRENT row) AS '6PSTDEV'
        [...] etc. /*8 rows*/

        FROM ra
        ) AS sub
    ) AS sub2
```

No doubt that this may be one of the most ineffective uses of SQL, but time-pressure and inexperience made me write it this way.

Any suggestions to change this code and achieve the desired table result more efficiently would be much appreciated too.

---

EDIT per Anton's answer;

The above code summarized as `pvt` continues as follows;

```
SELECT Number, LI, PHSE, combo, hitrate

FROM (...) AS pvt
UNPIVOT 
(Hitrate FOR Combo IN (
                       [0505],
                       [0506],
                       [...] etc.)) AS upvt
```

Great solution to an inelegant problem.

Comment: You've made the mistake of treating a database table as if it's a spreadsheet. It isn't, and you've ended up with a) repeating columns containing the same "type" of data and b) data not being stored as data but instead being stored in the metadata (here, column names). If you'd correctly modelled the data in the first place (with two columns for the model and the value, and so many more rows but fewer columns), the query would be easy to write.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this makes sense. The data is generated through subqueries in this format so the source isn't the issue. It's the method I applied to this point that seems ineffective; although the `unpivot` rearranges the data in the way you suggested, it seems a very ineffective detour. I will edit the question above to narrow down on this and see how the code can be made much more efficient. I've gone as far as using coalesce functions in excel to write the query considering all the variables involved. It's stupid I know, but time pressure and limited experience led me to this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use UNPIVOT, not PIVOT

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

If the number of columns is variable, you have to use dynamic sql to construct the list of columns

Comment: Great! Probably not the most sophisticated way to arrive at the conclusion, but it certainly worked!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CROSS APPLY` as follows:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (100254, 2, 'M1', 44, 46, 45, 44, 44),
    (100254, 2, 'M2', 36, 36, 35, 37, 37),
    (100254, 2, 'M3',  5,  5,  5,  5,  5),
    (100254, 2, 'R1', 34, 36, 37, 37, 37),
    (100254, 2, 'R2', 41, 41, 40, 41, 41),
    (100329, 1, 'M1', 37, 38, 38, 38, 39),
    (100329, 1, 'M2', 31, 29, 28, 29, 29),
    (100329, 1, 'M3',  6,  6,  6,  6,  6),
    (100329, 1, 'R1', 29, 29, 29, 30, 30),
    (100329, 1, 'R2', 25, 26, 26, 27, 26)) T(Number, LI, PHSE, [0505], [0506], [0507], [0508], [0509])
)
SELECT Number, LI, PHSE, MaxCol
FROM Src
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (VALUES
    ('0505', [0505]),
    ('0506', [0506]),
    ('0507', [0507]),
    ('0508', [0508]),
    ('0509', [0509])
    ) T(MaxCol, Val) ORDER BY Val DESC) Q
```

Note that equal columns may be chosen randomly unless some additional value is specified, i.e. MaxCol.

*Update*
You need dynamic query, like following one:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = 
    'SELECT Number, LI, PHSE, MaxCol
FROM Src
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (VALUES' +STUFF(
    (SELECT ',(', QUOTENAME(name, '''')+','+QUOTENAME(name)+')'
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('Src') AND name NOT IN ('Number', 'LI', 'PHSE')
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')+') T(MaxCol, Val) ORDER BY Val DESC) Q';
EXEC(@sql);
```

`Src` is your table name, replace it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but the table goes 64 columns across and 52K records down. Not an option...

Comment: In that case you need dynamic query, see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all MAXCOL (equal columns) try this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
Number NUMERIC(10),
LI numeric(10),
PHSE NVARCHAR(10),
[0505] numeric(10),
[0506] numeric(10),
[0507] numeric(10),
[0508] numeric(10),
[0509] numeric(10))

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100254,2,'M1',44  ,46 ,45 ,44,44)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100254,2,'M2',36,36,35,37,37)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100254,2,'M3',5,5,5,5,5)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100254,2,'R1',34,36,37,37,37)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100254,2, 'R2',41,41,40,41,41)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100329,1, 'M1',37,38,38,38,39)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100329,1, 'M2',31,29,28,29,29)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100329,1, 'M3',6,6,6,6,6)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100329,1, 'R1',29,29,29,30,30)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100329,1, 'R2',25,26,26,27,26)

SELECT *
INTO #UNPIVOT
FROM table1
UNPIVOT ( num
FOR MAXCOL IN ([0505],[0506],[0507],[0508],[0509])) AS k

SELECT A.Number,A.LI,A.PHSE,A.num,B.MAXCOL FROM
(SELECT number,LI,PHSE,MAX(num) AS num FROM #UNPIVOT GROUP BY number,LI,PHSE) A
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM #UNPIVOT) B ON A.num=B.num AND A.Number=B.Number AND A.LI=B.LI AND A.PHSE=B.PHSE
```

Comment: Thanks, but the table goes 64 columns across and 52K records down. Not an option...

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNPIVOT and CROSS APPLY.

With this solution you don't have to specify all the columns multiple times.

**Source data:**

```
CREATE TABLE Student
    ([Name] varchar(5), [Maths] int, [Science] int, [English] int)
;

INSERT INTO Student
    ([Name], [Maths], [Science], [English])
VALUES
    ('Tilak', 90, 40, 60),
    ('Raj', 30, 50, 70)
;
```

**Solution:**

```
with foo as (
   select name, subject, marks
   from student
   unpivot
   (
     marks
     for subject in (Science, Maths, English)
   ) u
)
select distinct f1.name, f2.subject
from foo f1
cross apply (
    select top 1 name, subject
    from foo
    where f1.Name = Name
order by Marks desc) f2
```

**Result:**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| Name           | Subject
--------------------------------------------------
| Tilak          | Maths
--------------------------------------------------
| Raj            | Science
--------------------------------------------------
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/780cd8/5